# Perfect fluids in cosmology?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, cosmology, thermodynamics

In cosmology, it is often assumed that the equation of state of a cosmological fluid is of the form $p=w\rho$. Why is this? Is it the equation of a [*perfect* fluid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_fluid)?

Why does $w=0$ for matter $1/3$ for radiation and $-1$ for a cosmological constant?

Comment: I take it [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_solution) doesn't help?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty It doesn't help *much*.

Comment: I think this is really two separate questions.

Comment: @BenCrowell I wouldn't know.

Comment: @user12345 John Rennie answered the main thrust of the question well, but I'll just say something about the first bit. $p=w\rho$ is *not* the equation for a perfect fluid, it is the *barotropic equation of state*. A perfect fluid is a fluid that has no viscosity. You can actually prove that for a homogenous and isotropic universe the energy-momentum tensor *must* be that of a uniform perfect fluid, but the equation of state is determined by other physics, as John Rennie discussed.

Comment: @MichaelBrown +1 that's one point I wanted to clear up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on the [equation of state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state_%28cosmology%29) discusses this.

### Matter

Consider non-relativistic matter first, because this is easy. We write the pressure as:

$$ p = \rho_m \space RT = \rho_m \space C^2 $$

where $\rho_m$ is the **mass** density, $RT$ is the thermal energy of the matter (or whatever) in your fluid, and $C$ is some sort of characteristic velocity. The justification for replacing $RT$ by $C^2$ is that kinetic energy is proportional to the square of velocity.

$\omega$ is given by:

$$ \omega = \frac{p}{\rho_e} $$

where $\rho_e$ is the **energy density** $\approx \rho_mc^2$, and substituting this into the above equation we get:

$$ \omega = \frac{\rho_m C^2}{\rho_m c^2} = \frac{C^2}{c^2} $$

and for non-relativistic matter $C \ll c$ so $\omega \approx 0$.

### Radiation

Now consider radiation, which is harder because we can't relate $p$ to a mass density. I don't know of an intuitive way to show this, but [this article](http://cosmology-lectures.angelfire.com/lecture3.pdf) goes into the details of calculating radiation pressure (it's complicated!!), and the final result turns out to be:

$$ p = \frac{1}{3} \rho_e $$

and obviously we immediately get $\omega$ = 1/3.

### Cosmological constant

Start with the Friedmann equation with a non-zero cosmological constant, $\Delta$:

$$ 3\frac{\ddot{a}}{a} = \Delta - 4\pi G(\rho + 3p) $$

we want to treat $\Delta$ as an effective pressure and energy density so we define:

$$ p_{eff} = p - \frac{\Delta}{8 \pi G} $$

$$ \rho_{eff} = \rho + \frac{\Delta}{8 \pi G} $$

We do this because now the Friedmann equation simplifies to:

$$ 3\frac{\ddot{a}}{a} = - 4\pi G(\rho_{eff} + 3p_{eff}) $$

as you can see by just substituting for $p_{eff}$ and $\rho_{eff}$ to get back the original Friedmann equation. So now we get an effective value for $\omega$:

$$ \omega_{eff} = \frac{p_{eff}}{\rho_{eff}}  = \frac{p - \frac{\Delta}{8 \pi G}}{\rho + \frac{\Delta}{8 \pi G}} $$

and if we assume that the cosmological constant is dominant, i.e. $p \approx 0$ and $\rho \approx 0$, we get the value of $\omega$ for just dark energy is -1.

Comment: Sorry for taking ages to respond. Your matter answer is really intuitive! The radiation one is good enough for me (i.e. 'it comes from the BB spectrum). However, the cosmo const.(CC) part makes little sense to me. +1 overall though. I think the $w=-1$ of the CC is what you get if you ask 'what is the vacuum energy density'. Perfect fluid: $T_{\mu\nu} = (\rho + p/c^{2})u_{\mu}u_{\nu} - pg_{\mu\nu}$. If $p=-\rho$ then $T_{\mu\nu}$ depends on $g_{\mu\nu}$ only, so it's a vacuum property... and we just call it the CC.

Comment: The link about the radiation fluid equation of state is dead. Any other references?

Comment: @juacala: fixed now!