# Equation of state in cosmology

Tags: cosmology

In cosmology we usually assume that the matter follows an equation of state given by

$$
P=w \rho.
$$
Given that we have a lot of non-standard theoretical proposals for field theories and exotic matter, is this equation always linear? Are there examples of theories where it is not? and how is this motivated?

Answer (score 2):

I'd put this as a comment, but don't have enough rep...anyway, as [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62039/perfect-fluids-in-cosmology) answer and the comments within state, the equation of state isn't necessarily linear. One thing I'd add is that one can *define* $w$ to be the ratio $\frac{P}{\rho}$ (as it's dimensionless), and since in general both pressure and density depend on time (no $\vec x$ dependence is allowed in a perfect FRW universe), then $w$ will be time dependent as well, hence the equation of state would be non-linear. An example of this would be a scalar field $\phi(t)$ with $w=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\dot\phi^2-V(\phi)}{\frac{1}{2}\dot\phi^2+V(\phi)}$, which is derivable from the energy-momentum tensor, and you can see that the ratio is time dependant as the scalar field evolves with the equations of motion. I suppose you could imagine some other kind of field (spinor, vector etc.), but I'm not sure if it would be compatible with the symmetries of the FRW metric.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Besides the fact that the relation (or w as you say) can be time dependent, my question is more related towards the fact that $\rho\propto P$  and not $\rho\propto P^2 $ for example.  Given the fact that the ratio is dimensionless, the relation might include another dimensionfull quantity and become non-linear. I wonder if there is a model that considers such case and if so how it is motivated.

Comment: Also,  I don't mind considering cosmologies that don't assume FRW, maybe some cosmological model assuming a different cosmology could allow for that behavior for the equation of state.

Comment: For an example of a nonlinear equation, you could for instance take the equation for a white dwarf, which is of the form $P\propto \rho^{\frac{5}{3}}$, source: http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/~chirata/ph236/2011-12/lec20.pdf. As for the second question, I can't say I'm aware of any cosmological (i.e. large scale) model that would use such an equation of state, mostly since there's plenty of evidence in favor of an FRW-like metric, and we're usually dealing with either matter, radiation, or a cosmological constant-like substance.

Comment: In theory, if you have a collection of particles, I think you should be able to calculate the pressure and density directly from the following formulas:
$P=\frac{g_x}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^3p\; d^3x\; f(x,p)\frac{p^2}{3E}$ and $\rho=\frac{g_x}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^3p\; d^3x\; f(x,p)\;E$, where $f(x,p)$ is the phase space density which depends on the physical coordinates and momenta, $g_x$ is the DOF of the particle, and $E$ is of course the energy of the particle. In kinetic equilibrium (the calculation performed usually), $f$ is just the Fermi or Bose distribution.